# Excel formula to count the number of matches in col A and col B

Tags: excel-formula

I have a table of data (below) in column A(ID) and B(Name). I would like help on creating a formula to count the number of consecutive occurrences in both A and B. The result column shows what I'm trying to create.

I can do it for one column using =IF(A1<>A2,COUNTIF($A1:A$1,A1),"")

I just can't get it to work using both columns

| ID | NAME | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | A Sapphire | 1 |
| 3 | B Diamond |  |
| 3 | B Diamond |  |
| 3 | B Diamond | 3 |
| 3 | C Ruby |  |
| 3 | C Ruby |  |
| 3 | C Ruby | 3 |
| 14 | B Diamond |  |
| 14 | B Diamond | 2 |
| 19 | A Sapphire | 1 |
| 19 | B Diamond | 1 |
| 25 | A Sapphire | 1 |
| 25 | B Diamond |  |
| 25 | B Diamond | 2 |
| 25 | C Ruby |  |
| 25 | C Ruby | 2 |
| 34 | A Sapphire | 1 |
| 34 | C Ruby | 1 |
| 39 | A Sapphire | 1 |
| 39 | C Ruby | 1 |
| 40 | C Ruby | 1 |
| 42 | C Ruby | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join data in A and B | Adding formula to C2: =A2&" "&B2
Then add formula to D1 =IF(C1<>C2,COUNTIF($C1:C$1,C1),"")

Copy formulas down

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNTIFS` which allows multiple ranges and criteria.
**COUNTIFS(criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2]…)**
`=COUNTIFS(B:B;B2;A:A;A2)`

Comment: COUNTIFS(B2:B23,B2,A2:A23,A2) is creating all the numbers in reverse, so adds 3,2,1, etc.. into each cell, which means I can't determine  the actual count in the result column. As a 1 or a 2 could be the whole count, middle of a count etc... I just need a single total in one cell for each set

Comment: Does the answer say `COUNTIFS(B2:B23,B2,A2:A23,A2)` ?

Comment: I have created a workable solution by concatenating A&B and then using my countif formula. I noticed that the countif formula I used for the ID numbers was not working for the names, because the numbers are unique and the names are not, so it was creating an accumulative count of the names. Using a join seems to have given me my answer.

Comment: You could answer your own question.